# Is there any app that show every coin(including litecoin) price and exchange?

Tags: exchange-rate, altcoin

M investing in a lot of altcoins but can't find any apps that support every existing coin's real-time price

Comment: have you tried https://coincap.io?

Comment: Nope 
havent tried it

Comment: coincap UI is not my style

Answer (score 1):

There are many applications you can try but I recommend you some of them those might be satisfactory, and I added brief comment for each.

1. Coin Alarm
   It allows you to track coin prices on your mobile and alarms you when your coin reaches an certain price.
2. Blockfolio
   It offers several tools to keep track of your coin investments. Plus it offers management tools on your portfolio.
3. TabTrader
   It allows users to buy and sell cryptocurrency assets within mobile interface and to check their prices real-time.

Comment: Is it available in Android?

Comment: yea, 
http://bit.ly/2uUiHtH